# Galois group of degree 3 extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

For $d$ not a perfect cube in $\mathbb{Q}$, I want to compute $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})/\mathbb{Q})$. I believe it has to be the trivial group, since it sends roots of the minimal polynomial $x^3-d$ to other roots, but the other 2 roots live in $\mathbb{C}$, which is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$. Hence the only option is $\sqrt[3]{d}\mapsto\sqrt[3]{d}$. Is this correct?

Comment: The symbol Gal is usually reserved to talk about automorphisms of fields that are normal over a given base field. But you are right, the Identity is the only $\mathbb Q$-automorphism of your field.